# Putting an ad always at the front on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ads, uitabview

I want to put an ad on my iPhone application.

And I'm using TabBar to separate some features.

Here's my question. I just want to put ONE AD which always should be displayed no matter what user select & switch between views by pressing tab-bar. I want that ad right above the tab-bar.

I don't want to put ad on every view nor refreshed every time user changes view.

Can somebody give me some idea??

thanks.

Comment: It's `AN AD`. All surrounding words must be capitalized along with it ;)

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that. Wondered what AD stood for, surely not Anno Domini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TabBarControllers view was added to the application `window` at some point.  This is usually in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method if doing it by code, otherwise it is done through Interface Builder.  Either way, if you want to add a view globally, do it at the end of `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and add it as a subview of the application `window`, not to any individual view controller.  Just ensure you are adding it after the tab bar controller as otherwise it will be covered up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to add ADBannerView to window. but I get this error. 'ADBannerView must be part of a view hierarchy managed by a UIViewController'

Comment: ok. add it to a dummy uiviewcontroller, then add the uiviewcontrollers view to the window.